# AFCI & GFCI nuisance tripping

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, afci

I just finished a new panel installation and the utility company just energized it. I completed the wiring for one circuit with a 20A AFCI breaker, when I plugged in an incandescent light the breaker tripped. I tried several other devices and the breaker kept tripping. The circuit has 2 receptacles, first is 4' from the panel and the second is 8' from the first one. I then wired a second 12' long circuit using a 20A GFCI with 1 receptacle on it with the same results. The utility voltage may be high. Could that be the cause?

Comment: I'd suspect a ground/neutral wiring fault. Household supply voltage is easily measured with a Cat II multimeter.

Comment: Did you install the breakers properly? The pigtail from the breaker goes to the neutral bar, the circuit hot goes to the brass terminal on the breaker, the circuit neutral goes to the silver terminal on the breaker. Also make sure the neutral and ground are not bonded anywhere along the circuit.

Comment: Does they breaker give any indication of what type of fault caused the trip?

Comment: AFCI false tripping reports can be made at http://www.afcisafety.org/report.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a [wiring tester](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LZTKIA) and verify the GFCI outlet is wired correctly.
2. Swap out he 20A AFCI breaker for a standard 15A or 20A breaker and then see if the GFCI outlet works after that.
3. Use a multimeter at the GFCI outlet to see if the voltage is in the expected range.
4. Post photos of wiring at all locations so we can better help you.

[image]